# Turkish Sunni Muslims

Tags: practical-islam, nikah, sunni

my question is Can Muslims (Specially Turkish Sunni Muslim) have two names? One as Public another as Nick name(which is completely different from his public name)? If yes then is it Haram to call/take his name infront of his family or/and friends? And why would he need to have two names?

Thanks

Comment: Why did you ask this question? I mean, what is the bond between this question & Islam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Turkish and I think I didn't understand your question quite well. A lot of Turkish people has 2 names, yes. But it is not different than having only 1 name. One is free to use either of them, or sometimes both together. Why would be using one of a person's names haram?

Names are determined by parents. Sometimes mother & father want different names for a child (usually grandparents would involve naming issue), and usually they put both of them. The child can use either of them, or both of them. Some people switch between their names if they have another friend with a single name which is same with their mostly used name in order to avoid collision.

Also some parents want to give some historical/famous names for their children like Mehmet Ali, Mehmet Emin, Ali Bahadır, etc.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, so are both the names legal? Yes He got really angry for using his nick name in public which I did not understand so asking all this....

Comment: Why I am asking this question in Islam forum to understand if there is any belief abiding from someone to use nick names in public.

Comment: Hmm, what was his name? Maybe it has a bad meaning in Turkish?

Comment: Its a strange name, I have never heard such name. Gizli means secret/hidden; Hisar means fort. Separately, they are fine; but I think some people may find them funny together. "Hidden fort"

Comment: i thought he was married or did something illegal with this name so he is hiding

Comment: Her initial question was [this](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23912/11938)

Comment: By the way, he actually might hiding his marriage. There are two kind of marriages in Turkey. Islamic marriage is not recognized by state. The state has another laic marriage system. Most people do both of them. A person with an Islamic marriage but without a state marriage can easily be seen as single, and you can't realize until you see the other woman.

Comment: Wow I wish details regarding different laws in different countries should be published online by Government of every country so frauds can be minimized. Anyways I am so thankful to 'Kalahari' and others to share and guide me in this situation.God Bless

Comment: I will favor friendship if His criminal background is clear which I am doubting too.

Comment: And I will really appreciate if he come to me and be truthful and stand by his words and be faithful.

Comment: @Rishita, I am sorry to say that, but this "conversation in the comments" issue is against the rules of this site. If we continue, the moderators will get angry. If you have still questions, please ask them separately. Have a nice day!